# How can I ungroup rows in Excel when the option in the ribbon doesn't work?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to bring the A value down into all the rows, then B, and then so on. The ungroup function doesn't work (the data was exported from Tableau) and there's way too many locations to do it manually. Is there a function that I can use to achieve this? I thought of grabbing the first value and then making the others zero and then implementing a function from there, but I'm getting stuck on how I'd do it.

A better illustration of what I'm trying to do:

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scS6v.png)

[my thought process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7GQD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that values "A" and "B" are just dummy data even though your START picture had actual location names. It's confusing when mixing real with dummy data when moving from one picture to the next.

At any rate, you can create an IF formula to get the location name to repeat.

Cell B2 formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),B1,A2)
```

So if cell A2 is blank, then populate B2 with B1, otherwise populate with A2. Drag it down and done.

[image]